# Apply graduated symbology renderer works in Python console but not in standalone script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology

I use the following PyQGIS script to load a vector layer from a shapefile and apply graduated symbology to it (tried to make it as minimalistic as possible). This works well in the QGIS 2.4 Chugiak Python console - the specified vector layer is loaded and graduated symbology is applied according to the arguments given to the function (`vectorLayer, targetField, classes, mode`).

However, when using this in a standalone script, I always get

```
layer loaded succesfully
ERROR 1: Argument of column Summary Function 'MIN' should be a column.
applying graduated symbology
ERROR 1: Argument of column Summary Function 'MAX' should be a column.
```

and no graduated rendering is applied. Any suggestions why this happens or how I can use `QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2` in a standalone script (preferably by using one of the existing rules instead of creating all classes on my own)?

Other functions like a more or less selfmade appliance of categorized rendering work well, so this does not seem to be a general issue with my Python/IDE/QGIS environment. I already made sure that my columns are numeric (and otherwise it would not work in the Python console).

Here is the code I use. When trying this out, make sure to adapt the parameters at the top to match your file. When trying it in the Python console, comment/delete the part at the top concerning `set up qgis app` and the last line `app.exitQgis()`, otherwise QGIS will probably crash.

```
# imports
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import os, glob

###########
# parameters
###########
pathToLayer = '/path/to/your/favorite/vectorLayer.shp'
targetField = 'someNumericColumnInTheVectorLayer'

pathToQGIS = '/path/to/your/qgis/folder/'

###########
# set up qgis app
###########
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(pathToQGIS, True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
app = QgsApplication([], True)


###########
# load a layer
###########
def loadVectorLayer(pathToLayer):
    vectorLayer = QgsVectorLayer(pathToLayer, 'ThisIsAVectorLayer', 'ogr')

    # validity check. if layer is valid, add to canvas
    if not vectorLayer.isValid():
        print "Layer failed to load!"
    else:
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLayer, True)
        print 'layer loaded succesfully'
        return vectorLayer


###################################
# function to apply graduated symbology to a layer
###################################
def applyGraduatedSymbology(vectorLayer, targetField, classes, mode):

    print 'applying graduated symbology'

    # set up renderer
    symbol =  QgsLineSymbolV2()

    colorRamp = QgsVectorGradientColorRampV2.create({'color1' : '0,255,0,255',
                                                     'color2' : '255,0,0,255',
                                                     'stops' : '0.5;255,255,0,255'})

    renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.createRenderer(vectorLayer, targetField, classes, mode, symbol, colorRamp)

    vectorLayer.setRendererV2(renderer)
    return


###################################
# main
###################################
def main():

    vectorLayer = loadVectorLayer(pathToLayer)

    applyGraduatedSymbology(vectorLayer, targetField, 3, QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.Jenks)

    print 'finished'

    return

main()

app.exitQgis()
```

Comment: Your script works fine here, you have also need of ```vectorLayer.triggerRepaint()``` into the ```applyGraduatedSymbology()``` method. The vector layer has need to be repainted in order to view it correctly onto map canvas.

Comment: Thx for your feedback. What platform are you using? I tried this with Windows 7 64bit and QGIS 2.4 and 2.6 64bit... I get the impression that this might be the problem or maybe some underlying dependencies like PyQT... I will try to test this on Linux or with the 32bit version soon.

Comment: I am on Linux 64bit. Sorry but maybe I am missing the question here. cannot you see the graduated classification over the legend tree or the mapcanvas? Also your script is working in python console but it's not as standalone script? and how you are running the standalone script?

Comment: Ok, sorry for the unclarity... Yep, when I run the script in the Python console, I can see the graduated classification in the legend and on the canvas as well (as expected). However, when using the same code in a standalone script, I get the error described above. I am running the standalone script on my system in PyCharm IDE, set up for Windows as [described here](http://nathanw.net/2014/05/10/setting-up-pycharm-for-pyqgis-and-qt/). This works fine when doing other stuff like categorized rendering, so it seems to work in general.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen graduated symbol documentation quite like that before. This code might be a bit more comprehensible and will probably solve your problem because I too use PyCharm IDE and I have used these graduated symbols many times.

```
 # create graduated marker symbol based on ('label', 'lower_range', 'upper_range', 'color')
colorRamp = (('label1', lwrTargetFieldVal, upprTargetFieldVal, '0,255,0,255'), \
           ('label2', lwrTargetFieldVal2, upprTargetFieldVal3, '255,0,0,255'), \
           ('label3', lwrTargetFieldVal3, upprTargetFieldVal3, '0.5;255,255,0,255'))
ranges = []
for label, lower, upper, color in colorRamp:
    rng = QgsRendererRangeV2(lower, upper, sym, label)
    ranges.append(rng)
field = "someNumericColumnInTheVectorLayer"
renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2(field, ranges)
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
```