# QGIS use Python script to show Hexabinning results instead of manually using Symbology

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

I am developing a hexabinning QGIS plugin. I have used the following script to perform hexabinning https://github.com/maphew/mhwcode/blob/1ef8338e20ff24ddbe741af225e556b9d81ec416/gis/qgis/h3-grid-from-layer.py

However, once the hexabinned layers are created, I have to manually perform the following steps on the layer to show the results.

Right click on the layer -> choose properties - > and set the value, symbol, and color ramp, and then click classify. Please refer to the image below.

In the plugin, it would be nice to automate the above tasks through code so that they are performed automatically when a user clicks the binning button, to prevent the user having to do all this.

I have written the following code, based on the answer here: [Applying categorized symbol to each feature using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175068/applying-categorized-symbol-to-each-feature-using-pyqgis?noredirect=1&lq=1)
It executes without errors, but the result layer (Hex 7) is empty. When I click on the layer (in the Layers panel) it does not show anything.

```
# Get the active layer (must be a vector layer)
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Hex 7")[0] # qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
   
# get unique values 
fni = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('numpoints') 
#layer.fieldNameIndex(1)
print('count ' + str(fni))
unique_values = layer.dataProvider().uniqueValues(fni)

# define categories
categories = []
count = 0
for unique_value in unique_values:
count = count + 1

    # initialize the default symbol for this geometry type
    # symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    print('total count ' + str(count))   
    

    # configure a symbol layer
    layer_style = {}
    layer_style['color'] = '%d, %d, %d' % (randrange(0,256), randrange(0,256), randrange(0,256))
    layer_style['outline'] = '#000000'
    symbol_layer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.create(layer_style)

    # replace default symbol layer with the configured one
    if symbol_layer is not None:
        symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)

        # create renderer object
        category = QgsRendererCategory(unique_value, symbol, str(unique_value))
        # entry for the list of category items
        categories.append(category)

    # create renderer object
    renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('test', categories)

    # assign the created renderer to the layer
    if renderer is not None:
        layer.setRenderer(renderer)

    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]

Please see the 22 second YouTube video that shows the process I want to automate.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNyMosEZx1o

**Result:**

**Useful links:**

[Qgis python to apply polygon Symbology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451612/qgis-python-to-apply-polygon-symbology)

[Categorizing by attribute using custom QGIS plugin via python programming?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213062/categorizing-by-attribute-using-custom-qgis-plugin-via-python-programming)

[Automatic pyqgis categorized renderer classification](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226642/automatic-pyqgis-categorized-renderer-classification)

[Applying categorized symbol to each feature using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175068/applying-categorized-symbol-to-each-feature-using-pyqgis)

[Update rule-based symbology QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445269/update-rule-based-symbology-qgis)

**Most helpful**

[Apply graduated symbology renderer works in Python console but not in standalone script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120509/apply-graduated-symbology-renderer-works-in-python-console-but-not-in-standalone)

Comment: can explain why this is not a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175068/applying-categorized-symbol-to-each-feature-using-pyqgis?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you. That seems helpful. Shoud I feed "numpoints" instead of "test" in line 7 "fni = layer.fieldNameIndex('test')"?

Comment: I will try to customise that. If that works, I will put the customised version as the answer to this question.

Comment: @IanTurton I have edited the question with code and results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

color_ramp = QgsStyle().defaultStyle().colorRamp('Spectral')

renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.createRenderer(
    vlayer=layer,
    attrName=layer.fields().names()[-1],
    classes=5,
    mode=QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Quantile,
    symbol=QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType()),
    ramp=color_ramp
)
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Works awesome! Just had to specify layername like this instead: "layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]"